# How to Loop Json data to view in react-native please

Tags: react-native

[image]

I want to loop some data from the json data that i map(white line area) in the pic into View(white line area)

Comment: Don't put code image. Add code to comments.

Comment: I want it too but stackoverflow reject it damp. How I gonna do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand what you want, you can do this inside the `View`:

```
{ result.map((item, index) => <ProductBox key={index} ...(props you want) />) }
```